# Set Specific list view for user

Tags: 2010, list, permissions, list-view

Hey i need to set a specific list view for certain users. They need to be able to view the list with a set view that they cannot change, and still be able to modify the list items.

HELP !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this, add the list as web part and then "edit webpart" and select the view, and in advanced option you can find target audience - give the set of user's namr or better if you have a group for that set of users (u might consider creating one if you dont have) give the group's name, and you are done, no other user will be able to see the content, and if you want to give oth